# How to get in browser window handles and be able to switch between tabs?

Tags: playwright, playwright-sharp

So im the process of moving from Selenium .net to PlayWrightSharp and something I do is get the current handles and be able to switch between tabs... Im unable to find a clear way to do this in playwrightsharp..

Example:
Selenium

```
        public IWebDriver ReturnlastKnownPageSession(IWebDriver _driver)
        {
            return _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
        }
```

PlayWriteSharp:

```
        [PlaywrightTest("browsercontext-basic.spec.ts", "should return all of the pages")]
        [Fact(Timeout = TestConstants.DefaultTestTimeout)]
        public async Task ShouldReturnAllOfThePages()
        {
            await using var context = await Browser.NewContextAsync();
            var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
            var second = await context.NewPageAsync();

            Assert.Equal(2, context.Pages.Length);
            Assert.Contains(page, context.Pages);
            Assert.Contains(second, context.Pages);
        }
```

there has to be something similar to selenium to get current browser and find all the pages in a single call and be able to switch between tabs

Any Thoughts out there?

Comment: I honestly think that navigating through the context.Pages is way way better than that SwitchTo approach from Selenium.

Comment: The context.pages doesn't seem to notice when new tabs are added....
has to be a cleaner way to do this.. wonder if there is a refresh option to the context can be updated on new changes..

Comment: Can you share a piece of code where the context.pages is not being updated? As you can see in the test, it should work as expected.

Comment: I guess I should provide more Context

i have a simple test that open a page, then clicks on a link.. that link open a new tab

I cant seem to find a clean way to get a new tab, without using  await browserContext.NewPageAsync(); - which open a new blank tab...

Answer (score 0):

You go about this a bit differently in Playwright.

You create a new context:

```js
context = await browser.newContext();
```

and page or pages within that context:

```js
let pages = [];
pages.push(await context.newPage());
pages.push(await context.newPage());
```

If you don't want to share cookies, cache, you create multiple contexts. Contexts don't share cookies, cache between each other, they are incognito-alike session within a browser instance.

Readings:

- https://playwright.dev/docs/core-concepts#browser-contexts
- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser?_highlight=newc#browsernewcontextoptions
- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser?_highlight=newc#browsernewpageoptions

Comment: Appreciate the example, but i'm using C# and not typescript... I dont see any push.. nor add? for IPage[] type in C#

Comment: I see. The principle holds, however. You can use some other collection C# provides and store references to contexts and pages in it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to keep track of the generated pages.

Comment: @hardkoded: csharpify it as much as you want :D I'd otherwise delete it, it's a bit off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I at least found a way to find the other tab in the same context

```
var popTask = await browserContext.WaitForEventAsync(ContextEvent.Page);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what @pavelsaman wrote and instead of an array just use a List,
then you can do the following:

```
var pages = new List<IPage>();
pages.Add(await context.newPage())
```

pages[index] will give you the page normally.